# Convert YUV to RGB on DeckLink using hardware

Tags: wpf, video-capture, hardware-acceleration, writeablebitmap, pixelformat

I'm currently ingesting HD1080p video at 59.94 FPS from a camcorder via the HDMI input on the DeckLink 4K Extreme.

My goal is to replicate the incoming image in a WPF UI element. To accomplish this I'm using the DeckLink SDK in a C# WPF application.

In this program I've implemented the VideoInputFrameArrived callback. In this callback I'm copying the bytes from each frame into a WriteableBitmap which I've set as the source for an Image.

All this works as it should, and when I run the program, the Image is indeed updated in real time as the frames arrive.

My problem then, is that the only two supported Pixel Formats for the video input are 8BitYUV and 10BitYUV, neither of which can be natively displayed on computer monitors.

The WriteableBitmap can only take in various RGB, Black and White, and CMYK formats.

Here is what I've tried so far.

---

I've tried to convert each frame using the IDeckLinkVideoConversion::ConvertFrame()

**Problem**: ConvertFrame() requires a destination frame to be rendered on the DeckLink using IDeckLinkOutput::CreateVideoFrame(). As I currently understand it, the DeckLink cannot act as both an input (to capture the video feed) and an output (to render the destination frame).

---

I've set the incoming stream to 8BitYUV, and copied each frame into the WriteableBitmap with a format of BGR32.

**Problem**: As I mentioned earlier, this will display an image, but the color is incorrect and the picture is only half the width that it needs to be.

The reason for this is that the incoming stream of 8BitYUV is 16 bits/pixel, whereas the Bitmap expects 32 bits/pixel, and so the Bitmap treats each incoming MacroPixel (4 bytes) as one pixel instead of the 2 pixels it really is.

---

Currently I'm using a pixel shader to fix the color and a RenderTransform to scale the Image horizontally by a factor of 2 to "fix" the aspect ratio. The porblem is that I have half of the original resolution.

I don't believe this is a hardware limitation, because when I hook up another monitor to the HDMI output on the DeckLink, the incoming picture displays in full 1080p in perfect color. Would it be possible to capture that outgoing stream somewhere in memory?

**TL;DR** 
What is the best way to convert 4:2:2 YUV (UYVY) into a RGB or CMYK pixel format in real time? (1080p @ 59.94 FPS)

Preferably a hardware solution i.e. DeckLink or GPU.

Comment: Hi, were you able to come up with a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options here.

First of all, you can display UYVY directly. Most video adapters will accept UYVY data through DirectDraw, DirectShow, DirectX versions up to 9 APIs and you won't need a real time conversion for the video frames. Integrating this into WPF application might require some effort, and perhaps the most popular way is to utilize DirectShow through [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library and [WPF Media Kit](https://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/). On this way, however, you could also capture video using DeckLink's video capture DirectShow filter. You could connect all parts together faster, however you already capture using [DeckLink SDK](http://update.blackmagicdesign.com/support/sdks) and this way you have more control and flexibility on the capture process so you might not want to get back to DirectShow.

Second option is to convert to RGB as you wanted. I don't think DeckLink can do it for you, and GPU based conversion definitely exists (the conversion formula is well known, simple and easy to parallelize), however is hardware dependent or otherwise not immediately available. Instead, Microsoft ships [Color Converter DSP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can do the conversion (from 8 bits, not 10 though) in a very efficient way. The API is native, and you might need [Media Foundation .NET](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/) to access it from your app. An alternate efficient software conversion can also be done using FFmpeg's libswscale (for managed app through respective wrappers).

Comment: Thank you Roman! I should have clarified that I specifically need the frames in RGB format, so that I can work with them as WPF UI objects. I've been trying to use Color Converter DSP, but am having some trouble. Media Foundation .NET will only work on Windows 7. Do you know of any examples where Color Converter DSP is used in a .NET environment?

Comment: Color Converter DSP is available with Vista or more recent, if this is OK for you, you can eventually use it your application through Media Foundation .NET or by taking respective part from it (I am not sure why it says it needs Win 7). If you need an alternate solution then you will have to find another third party scaler.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this with the decklink api because the card I have can act as both inputs and outputs.  And the outputs ***do not*** need to be in playback mode to access this part of the api:

```
com_ptr<IDeckLinkOutput> m_deckLinkOutput;
if (SUCCEEDED(m_deckLink->QueryInterface(IID_IDeckLinkOutput, (void **)&m_deckLinkOutput)))
{
    IDeckLinkMutableVideoFrame *pRGBFrame;
    if (SUCCEEDED(m_deckLinkOutput->CreateVideoFrame(videoFrame->GetWidth(), videoFrame->GetHeight(), videoFrame->GetWidth() * 4, bmdFormat8BitBGRA, videoFrame->GetFlags(), &pRGBFrame)))
    {
        m_deckLinkVideoConversion->ConvertFrame(pFrame, pRGBFrame);

        //use the rgbFrame

        pRGBFrame->Release();
    }
}
```